# bazel missing include directory in bazel-out

Tags: c++, bazel

I've noticed that when I try to build a c++ project with some flags, e.g., `"-Wall -Wmissing-include-dirs"`, bazel gives a missing include directory.

The project structure is the following

```
root
├── src
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── BUILD.bazel
│   └── main.cpp 
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── README.md
└── WORKSPACE
```

`src/main.cpp`

```sh
#include<iostream>
int main()
{   
    std::cout << "Compiled\n";
    return 0;
}
```

`src/CMakeLists.txt`

```sh
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(main)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -Wmissing-include-dirs -Ipath/that/doesnt/exist")

set(SOURCES main.cpp)
add_executable( main ${SOURCES})
```

`src/BUILD.bazel`

```
cc_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],
    copts = ["-Ipath/that/doesnt/exist -Wall -Wmissing-include-dirs"],
)
```

When compiling `main.cpp` with cmake (`mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make`), I see an expected warning for `path/that/doesnt/exist` (since it doesn't exist), e.g.,

```sh
cc1plus: warning: path/that/doesnt/exist: No such file or directory [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
```

but when I compile with bazel (`bazel build //src:main`) I get an additional missing include

```
cc1plus: warning: path/that/doesnt/exist: No such file or directory [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
cc1plus: warning: bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/bazel_tools: No such file or directory [-Wmissing-include-dirs]
```

***Question 1***: Where does `bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/bazel_tools` come from and why is it missing?

***Question 2***: How do I write my bazel build so that this warning doesn't appear?

If I were to remove the inclusion of `path/that/doesnt/exist` from the cmake and bazel builds, and compile with flags `-Wall -Werror -Wmissing-include-dirs`, then the cmake build succeeds, but the bazel one fails.

***Minimum working example found here:*** https://github.com/btk-learning/learn-to-build-cmake-bazel

Comment: Bazel deliberately includes directories that won't exist. If you build a `cc_library` with `includes` set, you'll get even more. That compiler flag isn't supported with bazel.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I updated the repo and added a `cc_library`. Here, I only get a missing include directory which is expected, e.g., `path/that/doesnt/exist`, but the missing `bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/bazel_tools` directory only appears  when I build a `cc_binary`.

Does bazel deliberately add extra include directories only for `cc_binary` targets?

Comment: That specific directory is added when any targets under the `@bazel_tools` external repository, which is a special one built into the bazel binary, are in the transitive dependencies of the target. `cc_binary.malloc` defaults to `@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:malloc`, which is an implicit dependency of every binary, so it will add that path even though it's typically an empty `cc_library`.